# Is flipping a coin is a stable rotation?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics, stability, gyroscopes

If I rotate a coin with dimensions: 10X10X1
about 1 of the big axes(10) in space, where there is no torque, will the rotation will be stable just like a frisbee or a football regular rotations are? please prove mathematically?
my proof tells me that this is not stable, am I wrong, where?
my proof: (assume coin is spheroid):

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373033/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to its disc-like shape, an ideal coin is symmetric and it has an infinite number of major axes (the axes aligned with the diameters of the coin). So technically, you have an infinite number of equilibrium points for the dynamics of the angular velocity. None of these equilibrium points is stable.

In the body-fixed coordinate system, centered at the center of the coin, with axes $x$ and $y$ along two of the major axes of the coin, and the $z-$axis perpendicular to the disc of the coin, the inertia tensor has zero off-diagonal components and 
$I_1 = I_2 = \frac{m}{12}(3r^2 + h^2)$ and $I_3 = \frac{m}{2}r^2$ where $r = 10h$ is the radius of the coin and $h$ is its thickness. Thus $I_3 > I_2 = I_1$

The equations of motion (Euler's equations) are
\begin{align}
&I_1\frac{d\omega_1}{dt} = (I_1 - I_3)\, \omega_2\, \omega_3\\
&I_1\frac{d\omega_2}{dt} = (I_3 - I_1)\, \omega_3\, \omega_1\\
&I_3\frac{d\omega_3}{dt} = (I_1 - I_1)\, \omega_1\, \omega_2 = 0
\end{align}
so if we set $k = \frac{I_3 - I_1}{I_1}$ the equations of motion become
\begin{align}
&\frac{d\omega_1}{dt} = -\, k\, \omega_2\, \omega_3\\
&\frac{d\omega_2}{dt} =  k\, \omega_3\, \omega_1\\
&\frac{d\omega_3}{dt} = 0
\end{align}
The third equation yields $\omega_3(t) = \omega_3^0$ for all $t$, so the equations of motion reduce to 
\begin{align}
&\frac{d\omega_1}{dt} = -\, (k\, \omega_3^0)\, \omega_2\\
&\frac{d\omega_2}{dt} =  (k\, \omega_3^0)\, \omega_1\\
&\omega_3 = \omega_3^0
\end{align}
The two by two linear system 
\begin{align}
&\frac{d\omega_1}{dt} = -\, (k\, \omega_3^0)\, \omega_2\\
&\frac{d\omega_2}{dt} =  (k\, \omega_3^0)\, \omega_1\\
\end{align}
has the solutions
\begin{align}
&\omega_1 = \omega_1^0\, \cos\Big((k\omega_3^0)\, t\Big) - \omega_2^0\, \sin\Big((k\omega_3^0)\, t\Big)\\
&\omega_2 = \omega_1^0\, \sin\Big((k\omega_3^0)\, t\Big) + \omega_2^0\, \cos\Big((k\omega_3^0)\, t\Big)\\
\end{align}
and the solution to the original system, describing the precession of the angular velocity, is
\begin{align}
&\omega_1 = \omega_1^0\, \cos\Big((k\omega_3^0)\, t\Big) - \omega_2^0\, \sin\Big((k\omega_3^0)\, t\Big)\\
&\omega_2 = \omega_1^0\, \sin\Big((k\omega_3^0)\, t\Big) + \omega_2^0\, \cos\Big((k\omega_3^0)\, t\Big)\\
&\omega_3 = \omega_3^0
\end{align}
If you want to understand the time-evolution of the angular velocity of the coin nearby a major axis, you can simply consider the $x-$axis, due to coin's symmetry. Then, start with an initial angular velocity $(\omega_1^0, \omega_2^0, \omega_3^0)$ with $\omega_2^0 = 0$ and $\omega_3^0 =\varepsilon$ a very small number. Then the time-evolution of the angular velocity is
\begin{align}
&\omega_1 = \omega_1^0\, \cos\big(k\varepsilon\, t\big)\\
&\omega_2 = \omega_1^0\, \sin\big(k\varepsilon\, t\big)\\
&\omega_3 = \varepsilon
\end{align}
which shows that staring from initial angular velocity $(\omega_1^0, 0, \varepsilon)$ after time $t = \frac{\pi}{2\,k\varepsilon}$ the angular velocity will be
$(0, \omega_1^0, \varepsilon)$ and then at time $t = \frac{\pi}{k\varepsilon}$ it will be $(-\omega_1^0, 0, \varepsilon)$ which is almost diametrically opposing the initial angular velocity. This means that very slowly, the axis of rotation aligned with the angular velocity will be drifting away from the $x-$axis. Hence, the latter is unstable. However, if you toss a coin, you would not see this clearly, unless you are in space, because the drift of the axis is very slow and the coin is going to land before any significant drift has occurred.

You can also see this behavior geometrically, using Poincot's ellipsoids: the one coming from the conservation of angular momentum
$$\big(I_1\omega_1\big)^2 + \big(I_1\omega_2\big)^2 + \big(I_3\omega_3\big)^2 = c_1$$
 and the other coming from the conservation of energy 
$$I_1\big(\omega_1\big)^2 +I_1 \big(\omega_2\big)^2 + I_3\big(\omega_3\big)^2 = c_2$$
The trajectory of the angular velocity is along one of the intersection curves of the two ellipsoids. In the case of the symmetric coin, the ellipsoids are rotational and have $z-$axes aligned, so the trajectory is a circle.

**Edit:** To make things a bit easier to visualize, it is a good idea to look at the dynamics of the angular momentum $\vec{l} = (l_1, l_2, l_3)$ in the body-fixed frame and compare it to its representation $\vec{L} = (L_1, L_2, L_3)$ in the world frame. There is a linear transformation between the angular momentum and the angular velocity in terms of the inertia tensor, i.e. 
\begin{align*}
&l_1 = I_1\, \omega_1\\
&l_2 = I_1\, \omega_2\\
&l_3 = I_3\, \omega_3\\
\end{align*}
so the dynamics of the angular velocity and the angular momentum are equivalent (isomorphic), i.e. whatever happens to one of them, the same thing happens to the other. 
Then the Euler's equations of motion become
\begin{align}
&\frac{d l_1}{dt} = \frac{(I_1 - I_3)}{I_1I_3}\, l_2\, l_3\\
&\frac{d l_2}{dt} = \frac{(I_3 - I_1)}{I_1I_3}\, l_3\, l_1\\
&\frac{d l_3}{dt} = \frac{(I_1 - I_1)}{I_1^2}\, \omega_1\, \omega_2 = 0
\end{align}
so if we set this time $m = \frac{I_3 - I_1}{I_1I_1}$ the equations of motion become
\begin{align}
&\frac{d l_1}{dt} = -\, m\, l_2\, l_3\\
&\frac{d l_2}{dt} =  m\, l_3\, l_1\\
&\frac{d l_3}{dt} = 0
\end{align}
The third equation yields $l_3(t) = l_3^0$ for all $t$, so the equations of motion reduce to 
\begin{align}
&\frac{d l_1}{dt} = -\, (m\, l_3^0)\, l_2\\
&\frac{d l_2}{dt} =  (m\, l_3^0)\, l_1\\
&l_3 = l_3^0
\end{align}
As before, the two by two linear system 
\begin{align}
&\frac{d l_1}{dt} = -\, (m\, l_3^0)\, l_2\\
&\frac{d l_2}{dt} =  (m\, l_3^0)\, l_1\\
\end{align}
has the solutions
\begin{align}
&l_1 = l_1^0\, \cos\Big((m l_3^0)\, t\Big) - l_2^0\, \sin\Big((m l_3^0)\, t\Big)\\
&l_2 = l_1^0\, \sin\Big((m l_3^0)\, t\Big) + \omega_2^0\, \cos\Big((m l_3^0)\, t\Big)\\
\end{align}
and the solution to the original system, describing the precession of the angular momentum, is
\begin{align}
&l_1 = l_1^0\, \cos\Big((m l_3^0)\, t\Big) - l_2^0\, \sin\Big((m l_3^0)\, t\Big)\\
&l_2 = \omega_1^0\, \sin\Big((m l_3^0)\, t\Big) + \omega_2^0\, \cos\Big((m l_3^0)\, t\Big)\\
&l_3 = l_3^0
\end{align}

Just like with the angular velocity, let us explore the stability of the $x-$axis of the body-fixed system. Observe, the $x-$axis is aligned with a diameter of the coin (this is not the $z-$axis which is goes through the center of the coin and is perpendicular to the coin!). We are in the body fixed frame. Let us start again from an angular momentum $(l_1, 0, \delta)$ where $\delta$ is a very small number. Then the time-evolution of the angular velocity is
\begin{align}
&l_1 = l_1^0\, \cos\big(m\delta\, t\big)\\
&l_2 = l_1^0\, \sin\big(m\delta \, t\big)\\
&l_3 = \delta
\end{align}
Denote $|\vec{l}| = \sqrt{l_1^2 + l_2^2 + l_3^2} = \sqrt{(l_1^0)^2 + \delta^2}$ and let us look at the change of distance between the angular momentum $\vec{l}$ and the $x-$axis $\vec{x} = ( \sqrt{(l_1^0)^2 + \delta^2}, 0, 0)$:
\begin{align}
\text{dist}\big(\vec{l}(t), \vec{x}\big)^2 &= |\vec{l}(t) - \vec{x}|^2={(l_1 - \sqrt{(l_1^0)^2 + \delta^2})^2 + l_2^2 + l_3^2}\\
&= {(l_1^0\, \cos\big(m\delta\, t\big) - p_0)^2 + (l_1^0\, \sin\big(m\delta \, t\big))^2 + \delta^2}\\
&= 2(l_1^0)^2 + 2\delta^2 - 2l_1^0\sqrt{(l_1^0)^2 + \delta^2}\, \cos\big(m\delta\, t\big) 
\end{align} This distance squared can be interpreted as a Lyapunov function and it changes from very closed to zero to a fairly large number. Since distance is the same in any Cartesian coordinate frame, this distance is the same in the body-fixed frame and in the world frame. Simply, in the body-fixed frame the $x-$axis $\vec{x}$ is fixed while the angular momentum $\vec{l}$ changes with time, while in the world coordinate frame the angular momentum $\vec{L}$ is fixed and the body-fixed axis $\vec{x}$ changes with time. In the body fixed frame the angular momentum     $\vec{l}$ precesses along a circle around the body-fixed $z-$axis, while in the world frame the body-fixed $z-$axis precesses along a circle around the fixed angular momentum  $\vec{L}$. Do not confuse the $x-$ and the $z-$axis. Their behaviors in the world system are different.

Comment: You have shown that the angular velocity has changed from (ω1,0,ε) after time t=π2kε to (0,ω1,ε) and then at time t=πkε to (−ω1,0,ε), but these component are in the rotating frame aren't they? so in the world frame, the rotation remains the same, isn't it?

Comment: @GuyAb No, it is the angular momentum in the world frame that stays the same. The angular velocity in the world frame in general does not. The axis of rotation of the body is always aligned with the angular velocity, not with the angular momentum. In the world frame, the angular momentum is $RJR^T\,\vec{\omega}$ where $J$ is the inertia matrix and the rotation matrix $R = R(t)$ is the time evolution of the body fixed frame with respect to the world frame, where $\frac{d R}{dt}\,\vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times R\,\vec{v}$ for any vector $\vec{v}$.

Comment: @GuyAb Plus, stability is a measure of the distance between the angular velocity, which is aligned with the momentary axis of rotation of the body, and the chosen body-fixed axis. Distance is the same in any coordinate frame. This means that if the distance between the angular velocity and the body-fixed axis grows with time in the body-fixed frame, it grows the same way in the world frame too.

Comment: @GuyAb Let me put it this way. Let us look at the angular momentum instead of the angular velocity (the dynamics is isomorphic). In the body-fixed frame, the body-fixed axis is stationary, while the angular momentum is drifting away from it. In the world frame, the angular momentum is stationary (i.e. fixed) while the body-fixed axis is drifting away from it. Either way, the angular momentum and the body-fixed axis are drifting apart with time.

Comment: I am almost sure that you have a mistake, see the following:

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QXRIinrGS0

Comment: in this motion, there is w3 and w1 component, but w1 is never able to complete a full circle, and according to your example it should

Comment: @GuyAb Yes, I am seeing it and there is nothing that contradicts the formulas from my answer. I suggest you spend a bit of time thinking about what is going on.

Comment: @GuyAb Even in this video the trajectory of the angular velocity (or better the angular momentum) in the body-fixed frame is a circle parallel to the $x,y-$plane of the body fixed frame. It's projection shows that $(\omega_1, \omega_2)$ traverse a full circle. However, in this video the blue axis is the one along the $z-$ axis of the body-fixed frame and the red one is the axis along the angular momentum. In your problem, you are asked abut an axis perpendicular to this $z-$axis, i.e. an axis lying on the $x,y-$plane (lying on the disc).

Comment: In the video, the major direction of the rotation (about z) is almost unchanged(counterclockwise) (with some wobbling along the x,y). In my case, the major rotation is along the x axis, according to your solution this major rotation will flip from clockwise to counterclockwise?

Comment: I mean in the world frame. by the way even here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-TnCMZF3fA                           the rotation direction in the world frame is unchanged - counterclockwise but in the body frame is changed,

Comment: @GuyAb No, the rotation is not goging to change from counterclockwise to clockwise. In the first video, the disc should be much more tilted, so that the red and the blue axes are almost perpendicular, not closed to being aligned. In the second video, the inertia ellipsoid of the body is not a rotational ellipsoid (it is not an ellipsoid with two equal principal axes). Nevertheless you can see how the middle principal axis of the body in the world frame flips from left to write and back to left and so on and so forth. Meanwhile, the angular momentum is fixed in the world frame.

Comment: Our notion of stability is different. 1) if we look at the Poincot's ellipsoids, does the coin rotation mainly about its diameter look like Poincot's ellipsoids picture of an asymmetric top rotating about its intermediate axis? 2) Does the coin that rotates mainly about its diameter will return after some time to its original position in space (in world co ordinates)?

Comment: @GuyAb 1) No, it doesn't; 2) In general it will not return exactly at the starting position but will be passing very close to it infinitely many times. It's angular momentum and its angular velocity however will return to their original positions in the body-fixed frame.

Comment: @GuyAb Oh, and I forgot to mention that in the inertial world frame, the angular momentum is constant, but the angular velocity, in general, changes, traversing a curve on the plane, perpendicular to the angular momentum passing through the momentum vector's tip, and that curve is in general not closed, so the angular velocity in world frame is not periodic.

Comment: @GuyAb I removed my last comment, because after some more careful thinking, I realized that I was right all along, so my preceding comments are correct.

Answer (score 1):

For other readers, a relevant reference for the equations used above is the Wikipedia page on the [tennis racket theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_racket_theorem).

Your proof demonstrates that, to first order, the stability is marginal.  This is what you showed by demonstrating that (to first order) $d \omega_x' = d \omega_z' = 0$.  That is, it is on the border of stable and unstable.  Any initial perturbation will neither grow nor shrink but will stay the same size.

At the end you show that $d \omega_y'$ is given by a constant that has the same sign as $d \omega_z$.  I could not find an error in the derivation after a few minutes, so although I am not completely sure it is correct, it probably is.  The conclusion is probably still incorrect, though.  A perturbation that grows linearly in time might still be called marginally stable by most physicists.  It is still quite different than the usual stable/unstable cases, where the perturbation will either grow or shrink exponentially in time.

Answer (score 0):

with the "tennis racket theorem" you get this differential equation:

$\ddot{\omega}_y=-k\,\omega_y$

so the solution is: (with the initial condition $\omega_y(0)=A\,,\quad D(\omega)_y(0)=0$ )

$\omega_y(t)=A\cos(\sqrt{k}) $

if $k \ge 0$ you get a stable solution.

if $k < 0$ the solution is unstable ( $\omega_y(t)=A\,\cosh(\sqrt{k}\,t)$

with:

$k={\frac {{\Omega_{{x}}}^{2} \left( -I{\it yy}+{\it Ixx} \right) 
 \left( {\it Ixx}-{\it Izz} \right) }{{\it Iyy}\,{\it Izz}}}
$

your case:

$Ixx=Iyy=\frac{M*(b^2+s^2)}{5}$

$Izz=\frac{2\,M\,b^2}{5}$

$\rightarrow$

$k=0$ stable system!

Comment: $k=0$ is typically called "marginally stable" rather than "stable."

Comment: Connection to the OP's solution and also to my answer: Note that $\omega_y'' = -k \omega_y$ has solutions $\omega_y = c_1 t + c_2$.