# A subtlety about Lyapunov stability of stationary rotations of rigid body

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, stability, chaos-theory

On Page 145 of Arnold's mechanics book there is the [intermediate axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_racket_theorem):

> "The stationary solutions of the Euler equations corresponding to the largest and smallest principal axes [of the inertia ellipsoid for a rigid body] are stable while the solution corresponding to the middle axis is unstable."

Right afterwards there is a problem:

> "Problem: Are stationary *rotations of the body* around the largest and smallest principal axes [Lyapunov stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability)? Answer: No."

How is this not a contradiction?

---

I suppose one could describe a body using a reference frame whose origin was away from the body's center of mass. Then obviously rotation of such a body about the inertia ellipsoid's axes might not be a stable rotation. But such a reference frame seems out of context for this discussion.

Comment: Oh, it's the *angular momentum trajectories* that are stable or unstable. The *rotations of the body* themselves over time are not stable.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first recall how the [Euler equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics)) simplifies sufficiently close to a principal axis, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373033/2451) Phys.SE post:

1. The major axis $\vec{\Omega}\approx (\Omega_1,0,0)$ is stable because 
   $$\ddot{\Omega}_i~\approx~-\omega^2_1 \Omega_i, \qquad i\in{2,3}, \tag{1a}$$
   where
   $$\omega_1~:=~\Omega_1\sqrt{\frac{(I_1-I_2)(I_1-I_3)}{I_2I_3}}. \tag{1b}$$
2. The [intermediate axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_racket_theorem) $\vec{\Omega}\approx (0,\Omega_2,0)$ is $\color{red}{\text{unstable}}$ because
   $$\ddot{\Omega}_i~\approx~\color{red}{+}\omega^2_2 \Omega_i, \qquad i\in{1,3}, \tag{2a}$$
   where
   $$\omega_2~:=~\Omega_2\sqrt{\frac{(I_1-I_2)(I_2-I_3)}{I_1I_3}}. \tag{2b}$$
3. The minor axis $\vec{\Omega}\approx (0,0,\Omega_3)$ is stable because 
   $$\ddot{\Omega}_i~\approx~-\omega^2_1 \Omega_i, \qquad i\in{1,2}, \tag{3a}$$
   where
   $$\omega_3~:=~\Omega_3\sqrt{\frac{(I_1-I_3)(I_2-I_3)}{I_1I_2}}. \tag{3b}$$

For each of the stable axes, we see that 2 small perpendicular angular velocity components $\Omega_i$ are 2 independent harmonic oscillators. If they at some instant happens to vanish, there is no guarantee that they will stay that way in the future. In particular, they are *not* [Lyapunov stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability).